# Directory not being recognized

Tags: java, file, directory

So I have a method that reads all the files in a folder and creates new classes in a List with the variables read from the files. For some reason it doesn't ever get past the `if(mainDir.isDirectory()){` part, even though the paths are correct and I double checked the folders were there.

```
public static void loadIntoClass(String dir, int temp){
    try {
        File mainDir = new File(dir);

        if(mainDir.isDirectory()){ //Checks if the dir is a folder and not a file

            String[] fileNames = mainDir.list(); //Grabs a list of all the filenames in the dir

            for(int x = 0; x > fileNames.length; x++){ //loops through all the files

                File currFile = new File(dir + fileNames[x]); //Creates the object we will be gathering information from

                if(currFile.isFile()){ //Checks to make sure the file is a file and not a folder

                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(currFile)); 
                    String line = br.readLine();

                    int currLoop = 1;
                    boolean collides = false;

                    while(line != null){ //Will keep checking files until it reaches a blank line

                        currLoop ++; //Keeps track of how many times it loops

                        test = line.split("="); //Splits up the variable from the declaration
                        String toString = test[0].trim(); //Trims off any extra blank spaces on either side

                        System.out.println("Reading: " + toString + " on line " + currLoop); //For debugging
                        String toString2 = test[1].trim(); //Trims the second string

                        parse[currLoop] = Integer.parseInt(toString2); //Turns the string into an integer then puts it into the array

                        if(toString.equalsIgnoreCase("Collides")){
                            if(toString2.equalsIgnoreCase("true")){
                                collides = true;
                            }
                        }

                        if(toString.equalsIgnoreCase("Image Path")){
                            //path = toString2;
                        }

                        line = br.readLine();
                    }

                    if(temp == 1){
                        types.add(new Type(parse[1], parse[2], parse[3], parse[4], parse[5], parse[6], parse[7]));
                    }

                    if(temp == 2){
                        tiles.add(new Tiles(parse[1], collides, null));
                    }

                    if(temp == 3){
                        abilities.add(new Abilities(parse[1], parse[2], parse[3], parse[4]));
                    }
                    br.close();
                }
            }
        }

    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.err.println("ERROR: " + e);
    }
}
```

After that if I change it some other path like "C:/test" it works only to freeze at the for loop. Here's the declaration:

```
loadIntoClass("C:/Program Files(x86)/GameNameHere/config/enemies", 1);
```

Comment: it wold be helpful if you can post thh rest of the code.

Comment: I'd be worried about `File currFile = new File(dir + fileNames[x])`, this may produce `"C:/Program Files(x86)/GameNameHere/config/enemiessomefilename.ext"` which isn't what you want.  Instead simply use `mainDir.listFiles()` which will return an array of `File`

Comment: Are you sure you have the name of the directory correct? On Windows it's normally called `C:\Program Files (x86)` not `C:\Program Files(x86)` - note the missing space before `(x86)`.

Comment: or use new File(mainDir, fileNames[x]).

Comment: Can you please try if `mainDir.isFile()` returns true?

Comment: 1) Change code of the form `catch (Exception e) { ..` to `catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); // very informative! ..` 2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

The methods isDirectory() and isFile() doe not work if the underlying FS-Objects do not exist.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple possible issues, which you are not taking into consideration...

- Your not checking to see if the `dir` exists
- Your not making sure to close your files in case of an read error (or other associated error)
- You making life tough for yourself using `File#list`, instead use `File#listFiles` which will return an array of `File`
- Make better use of exceptions...

For example...

```
public static void loadIntoClass(String dir, int temp) throws IOException {
    File mainDir = new File(dir);

    if(mainDir.exists) { // Check to see if the abstract path actually exists
        if (mainDir.isDirectory()){ //Checks if the dir is a folder and not a file

            File[] fileNames = mainDir.listFiles(); //Grabs a list of all the filenames in the dir
            //String[] fileNames = mainDir.list(); //Grabs a list of all the filenames in the dir

            if (fileNames != null && fileNames.length > 0) {
                //for(int x = 0; x > fileNames.length; x++){ //loops through all the files
                for(File currFile : fileNames){ //loops through all the files
                    //File currFile = new File(dir + fileNames[x]); //Creates the object we will be gathering information from
                    if(currFile.isFile()){ //Checks to make sure the file is a file and not a folder
                        BufferedReader br = null;
                        try {
                            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(currFile));
                            String line = null;

                            int currLoop = 1;
                            boolean collides = false;

                            while((line = br.readLine()) != null){ //Will keep checking files until it reaches a blank line
                                //...//
                            }

                            //...//

                        // Make sure you make all best attempts to close the reader...
                        } finally {
                            try {
                                br.close();
                            } catch (Exception exp) {
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                // You may not care, but...
                throw new IOException(dir + " does not contain any files");
            }
        } else {
            throw new IOException(dir + " is not a directory");
        }
    } else {
        throw new IOException(dir + " does not exist");
    }
}
```

Comment: The smallest mistakes are the hardest to find; I probably could have fixed it by adding a + "/" + to the directory name. I will definitely change my code to make it less susceptible to mistakes in the future by adding more ifs and elses like you suggested, along with other things. Thanks for your time lol